How to get id of previous element, before iframe?
This should be simple but it seems not to be.  This is my HTML:
<div id="mask" class="hide">
 <div id="page" style="height: 90%; width: 475px;">
  <iframe id="modal" class="iframe" src="blank.php"></iframe> 
 </div>
</div>

This is my Javascript:
 let modal = document.getElementById("modal");
 console.log(modal.previousSibling.id); // show undefined
 console.log(modal.previousElementSibling.id); // throws JS error: null

So how do I get the id's of the 2 previous divs, no jquery please?  The iframe is not open at this time and I'm not inside the iframe when I run the JS.  I have searched alot but found nothing that fits my needs.
Thank you for any and all help,
Charles

Those are not previous siblings. Those are the parent elements wrapped around the iframe.

What about use let pageDiv = modal.parentElement;
let maskDiv = pageDiv.parentElement; so when you log the items you should see this : console.log(pageDiv.id); // Outputs: page
console.log(maskDiv.id); // Outputs: mask

What you need to get is parent element, not previous sibling.
<div id="mask" class="hide">
 <div id="page" style="height: 90%; width: 475px;">
  <iframe id="modal" class="iframe" src="blank.php"></iframe> 
 </div>
</div>

iframe#modal does not have any previous sibling elements. div#page is parent  element for iframe#modal, and div#mask is parent for div#page.
If you need to get to parent of parent of the modal here is what you can do:
const modal = document.getElementById("modal");
const maskElement = modal.parentElement.parentElement;

// id of the element
console.log(maskElement.id)


next, i assume you might want to toggle hide class for mask to show your iframe:
maskElement.classList.toggle("hide")


I'm sure I tried parentElement and got a function not defined error.  Maybe I misspelled it or my brain was stuck in a loop.  Thanks for the help.
